# Passing atributes to the view in a Spring Security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring application, the login process is handled by spring security using the UserDetailsService and BCryptPassword classes. When the login is successful, this class redirect the use to the main page:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        SavedRequest savedReq = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.ACCESS_DENIED_403);

        if (savedReq == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/acesso/home");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/acesso/login?erro=no_permit");
        }
    }

}
```

In the jsp page, I can get the username using this expression:

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

But, in my database, I also have stored the first and last name. I need, in the class above (or in any place possible), pass this data to my view. I try this:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("username", "Usuario Teste");
```

using this in the view: `${username}`, but when I run the application, nothing is displayed.

Anyone can point me a way to do that?

**my spring security configuration**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/publico/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/acesso/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("login")
            .passwordParameter("senha")
            .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/acesso/login").permitAll();
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Authentication Provider**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService usuario;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails user = usuario.loadUserByUsername(name);

        if(encoder.matches(user.getPassword(), password)) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
            return auth;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class AcessoService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome accountDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario account = accountDao.findByField("login", username);

        if(account==null) {
            System.out.println("No such user: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
        } else if (account.getAutorizacao().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("User " + username + " has no authorities");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");
        }

        List<Permissao> lista = new ArrayList<Permissao>();
        int max = account.getAutorizacao().size();
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            int max2 = account.getAutorizacao().get(i).getPermissao().size();
            for(int j=0; j<max2; j++) {
                lista.add(account.getAutorizacao().get(i).getPermissao().get(j));
            }
        }

        boolean accountIsEnabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(account.getLogin(), account.getSenha(), accountIsEnabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(lista));
    }

    public List<String> getRolesAsList(List<Permissao> list) {
        List <String> rolesAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Permissao role : list){
            rolesAsList.add(role.getNome());
        }
        return rolesAsList;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<Permissao> list) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRolesAsList(list));
        return authList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor are storing your "username" data in session.

You can try to get it in one of this two ways.

`request.setAttribute("username", "Usuario Teste");` and then yo can use ${username} EL directly. Or you can use `request.getSession().setAttribute("username", "Usuario Teste");` with ${sessionScope.username} EL.

You must to know the differents between session and request scopes.

PD:
Read [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2064/jsp-expression-language-el-example-tutorial).

In another side, to get the username in Spring Sec yo can try to use `<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />`

And, if you want to use more complex objects than one String as principal, you can extends the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

Comment: I already extending AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService (see my update). I need extend another class to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Comment: You should return your own UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken from CustomAuthenticationProvider, then your token is retrieved for UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and setting in the SecurityContext.